# Update in O(log n) time

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Is there any way to update the nodes of the balanced binary search tree in O(log n) time?

Suppose there is a balanced tree such that each node have an indexed object associated with it. So node 1 will point to object 1, node 2 will point to object 2 and so on.

If there are 100 nodes in the tree and if someone decided to delete the 2nd node then we have to update the remaining nodes such that node 3 will now be pointing to node 2, node 4 will now be pointing to node 3 and so on.

But this method will take O(n) time.

How can this be done in O(log n) time?

Comment: i was looking through red black tree for the updation.
But it handles only deletion which takes O(log n) time but the updation of nodes still takes O(n) time.

Comment: I guess you meant after deletion, node 3 points to object 2, node 4 points to object 3? What is the purpose of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

If your tree is implemented such that each node has references to its children, i.e.:

```
class Node<T>
  Node leftChild
  Node rightChild
  T Data
```

(as opposed to an array or another way) all you have to do update these references (as outlined on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) for a Red-Black tree, for example).

This process will take O(log n) time, not O(n) time.

If you delete element 2 from the tree, node 2 will go along with it.

Answer (score 0):

That property sounds more like a linked list that a tree. But deletion in a binary search tree is `O(h)`, the height of the tree. Since it's balanced this is `O(log n)`.